# Set SelectionModel for TableView in FXML

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, selectionmodel

I want to set the SelectionModel of the TableView from the FXML, but I can not find how to do this. I already tried the following:

1.Just set it as a property of the TableView:

```
<TableView selectionModel="MULTIPLE">
```

2.Set the property the same as the ListView works (see: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2315611?start=0&tstart=0):

```
<TableView multiSelect="true">
```

3.Set the property in a different way:

```
<TableView>
    <selectionModel>
        <TableView fx:constant="MULTIPLE" />
    </selectionModel>
</TableView>
```

4.Another version:

```
<TableView>
    <selectionModel>
        <SelectionModel fx:constant="MULTIPLE" />
    </selectionModel>
</TableView>
```

5.Selection model (different):

```
<TableView>
    <selectionModel>
        <SelectionModel selectionModel="MULTIPLE" />
    </selectionModel>
</TableView>
```

None of this works.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should it be possible on FXML this should be the way:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" >
    <columns>
      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
    </columns>
    <selectionModel>
        <SelectionMode fx:constant="MULTIPLE"/>
    </selectionModel>
</TableView>
```

Unfortunately, when you run it you get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce SINGLE to class javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:495)
```

This is happening because the bean adapter tries reflexively to find in the class `javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel` the `valueOf` of `javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`, but it doesn't find it.

There's an unresolved JIRA ticket for this [here](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19198).

The only working solution I've found, based on that report, is using scripting capabilities:

```
...
<?language javascript?>

    <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" >
        <columns >
          <TableColumn fx:id="col" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>
    <fx:script>          
          table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    </fx:script>
```

Which is the same as doing it by code...

Comment: Thanks for your answer José Pereda! Until it is resolved, I will just set that part in code.

Comment: Or do it in the initialize method of your controller.